# What Stack Exchange site is best suited for questions on OpenShift?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site for questions on [OpenShift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShift)?

- Questions tagged `openshift` on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) receive moderate attention and some very good answers, typically from [Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) (of Red Hat). Currently there are 5180 such questions. However, just yesterday I've seen [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340155/can-start-nginx-manually-inside-docker-container-but-not-automatically-via-cmd) receive a close request because "this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center" and its answer being downvoted perhaps for the same reason as well. Under such a strict interpretation of programming vs. devops many/most of the other current `openshift` questions on Stack Overflow would seem doubtful as well.
- Questions tagged `openshift` on [DevOps Beta](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) seem to receive far less attention. Currently there are only 11 questions tagged `openshift` and @GrahamDumpleton apparently does not even have an account on that site. Perhaps the (beta) site is too new, because on first sight it would seem like a perfect fit for OpenShift; or perhaps it has already fallen victim to a network effect opposite Stack Overflow and won't be able to catch up.

Given these observations (plus your own educated opinions), what is the best Stack Exchange site for receiving good answers to questions on OpenShift? I am interested in an "is" (less an "ought") perspective. Also, does Red Hat encourage use of a particular site?

Comment: Just to note: just because a question about Openshift is on-topic on Stack Overflow, that does not imply that ALL questions about Openshift are on-topic on Stack Overflow. The question you linked to does not even seem to be really specifically about Openshift but rather about Docker. Follow up note: one close request is not truth, it is only one request. There is a reason several close requests are needed before the request is honored, people make mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, does Red Hat encourage use of a particular site?

Not an official answer, and I don't know if the OpenShift team has any special policy, but as a former Red Hatter I can say the vibe was to always go where the community is, be it IRC, a mailing list, a discord forum or a Stack Exchange site instead of trying to dictate where it should be.